# Get username and timestamp of instagram media id using intagram graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-graph-api

I want to find all recent media with a specific hashtag on Instagram.
It's described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/hashtag-search/)

To get media with the specific hashtag I have used :

```
GET graph.facebook.com/17873440459141021/recent_media?user_id=17841405309211844
```

The result is a list of [IG media](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media/) ids

Problem is that I am not able to use that id in [ig media node](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media/) to get the username and timestamp. This node operates on ig_id and I have just an id.

It is possible to add fields to [recent_media node](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/hashtag/recent-media), but it's not possible to get timestamp and username.

Does anyone know how to get a username and timestamp from Instagram media id?

Comment: Any success with answering this question?

Comment: @Maniek What I can see is you can get media_id from recent-media followed by GET /{ig-media-id}?fields={fields}
Then in fields, you can pass username,timestamp

Comment: @Maniek, you said that node operates on ig_id then how can I get that using ig_id?
plz share your experience.

Comment: Hi @thinkmore, we were not able to get that using ig_id, it seems like its not possible. unfortunetley